# Insect Egg Case, and if so, What Insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Observed this object today (early October) in Sabino Canyon, on the north side of Tucson AZ, in a riparian area.  It's attached to a mesquite tree (*Prosopis* spp).  It's attached to one side of the branch, it does not wrap around the branch.  About 1.5 - 2 cm along the maximum dimension.

Looks like some kind of insect egg case and I'm curious if anyone can confirm and knows the insect.

[image: mystery object]

Answer (score 2):

A local graduate student relayed the answer to me.  It is an ootheca of a praying mantis.  There is some additional background on the egg life history [here](https://tucson.com/eggs-of-the-praying-mantis/article_c2d601ca-dd07-11e6-9ff7-3bc386284336.html).  Wikipedia reports there are three mantid [species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arizona_mantis).  The upper-left picture of the ootheca [here](http://arizonabeetlesbugsbirdsandmore.blogspot.com/2015/01/all-about-mantids.html) is essentially what I observed, so we may be looking at the genus *Stagmomantis*.  There are some other great pics at that last site.

Comment: Hi Bryan, self answers are great but we like answers to have some support and a bit more information than one line. If someone gave you a tip, now you could write a good answer by using that tip to find a reputable source that describes a praying mantis ootheca that looks like yours, include a cited picture, and maybe even get a guess at a particular species based on your location, if possible.

Comment: I shall expand the answer in a few minutes.